# When I try to move a model everything in a circle around it moves as well

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

When I try to move a model everything in a circle around it moves as well. I was not having this problem and now I am.

[image]

Comment: You have proportional editing turned on. Press "o" to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

You have proportional editing turned on. Look at the middle on the bar at the top, the thing that looks like a target sign. It is blue in your case, meaning it is enabled. Click it, or press <kbd>O</kbd> to turn it off.

Proportional editing allows you to affect the movement of nearby objects when moving one. It is useful in some cases, like in edit mode when you want to create smooth bumps but don't want to move individual vertices.